# Why is R function parse substituting semicolons with commas?

Tags: r

I have to consecutively plot lots of variables against a fixed one using ggplot2 in R. For doing so, I wrote a for cycle generating the code lines like this:

```
l <- "ggplot(data = db)+geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = copper), colour = 'tomato')+geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = db[['"
x <- vector()
for (j in (3:ncol(db))){
     n <- colnames(db[,j])
     k <- paste0(n, "']]), colour = 'blue')+labs(title = 'copper & ", n,"'); ")
     x <- paste0(x,l,k)
}
eval(parse(text=substr(x, 1, (nchar(x)-1))))
```

Where in the for cycle I conclude each graph generation with a semicolon, so that R recognizes groups of code to be evaluated separately. At this stage the code is stored into a string. Then I use the function `parse` and `eval` to evaluate the string and execute it as code.

However, after I run the for cycle, in `x` I have that each graph code is separated by a semicolon `;` while after using the function parse the semicolons become commas `,`.

This makes my for cycle useless, since R does not recognize different groups of code.

Any idea why this happens and how can I keep the semicolon after `parse`?

Comment: Try using `n <- as.character(colnames(db)[j])`

Comment: Thanks, Marco. That did not eliminate the issue with parse unfortunately

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible so that it is easier for others to help you?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use semicolons; `parse` would accept newlines between commands, e.g.:

```
eval(parse(text='print(3+3)\nprint(4+4)'))
# [1] 6
# [1] 8
```

Further, you might consider the following cleaner version of your code:

```
code_fmt = "
ggplot(data = db) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = copper), colour = 'tomato') + 
  geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = db[['%s']]), colour = 'blue') +
  labs(title = 'copper & \"%s\"')
"
plots = sapply(tail(colnames(db), -2L), function(nm) {
  parse(text = sprintf(code_fmt, nm, nm))
})
eval(plots)
```

Using `code_fmt` allows us to cleanly write what the full expression will look like, properly indented and everything. You could also replace the `%s` with e.g. `{nm}` and replace the values with the `glue` package rather than `sprintf`.

`tail(x, -n)` returns elements `(n+1):length(x)`, i.e., excluding the first `n` elements

`sapply` here will return an `expression(...)`; `eval(expression(...))` evaluates the elements in sequence, e.g. consider:

```
eval(expression(print(3+3), print(4+4)))
# [1] 6
# [1] 8
```

Further further, I don't see why you need `eval(parse` in the first place -- what's wrong with a simple loop?

```
for (nm in tail(colnames(db), -2L)) {
  ggplot(data = db) + 
    geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = copper), colour = 'tomato') + 
    geom_line(aes(x = asofdate, y = db[[nm]]), colour = 'blue') +
    labs(title = sprintf('copper & \"%s\"', nm))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, absolutely great explanation and I very much agree with everything. However, when I try the solution with code_fmt only the last plot is generated. While when I try the last solution without eval(parse), no plot at all is printed. Do you know why and how this could be avoided? Many thanks again!