# How to plot ts in multiple plots in R?

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to master plotting skills in R and for the purpose I am using the following code to generate various time series plots all at once.

```
pl <- as.character()
for (k in (2:ncol(db))){
    h <- paste0("ts.plot(cbind(db[,1], y = db[,",k,"]), type = 'b', 
            gpars = list(col = c('black', 'red')), 
        main = 'copper & ",colnames(db[,k]),"');")      
    pl <- paste0(pl, h)
}
eval(parse(text=substr(pl, 1, (nchar(pl)-1))))
```

The code works fine, however I do not manage to understand something:

- here I am always trying to plot the series in `db[,1]` against all the others. How can I plot them into two separate plots one above another using `ts.plot`?
- how can I change the aestetics from points to lines?

I know a better graphical set can be achieved with `ggplot2`. However, using the same idea with `ggplot2` failed to generate the graphs, either none of them or only the last one (check also what I previously posted here, if you have a better solution please feel free to share: [Why is R function parse substituting semicolons with commas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224522/why-is-r-function-parse-substituting-semicolons-with-commas/59225705#59225705))

In any case, I would be very happy if someone could help with with the two above.

Please, use this `db` to reproduce my example (any time series would work)

```
library(stats)
set.seed(1)
x <- stats::rnorm(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
y<- stats::rnorm(n = 100, mean = 1, sd = 1)
z <- stats::rnorm(n = 100, mean = 2, sd = 1)
u <- stats::rnorm(n = 100, mean = 3, sd = 1)
db <- cbind(x,y,z,u)
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example of the data you are trying to plot ? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Interesting question. But to help, we would be very happy if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451). Maybe too can you sketch out your desired result maybe with image software if you cannot render it yourself?

Comment: Thanks @dc37, Parfait, I edited adding some data for db. Indeed I am working on some random time series, so any matrix of floats works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick question: Does the use of `parse` and `eval` is mandatory ? In my answer, I'm not using it to simplify the code. You will have to put it back if you need but it should be quite easy.

Regarding your second questions, to have `lines` instead of `points`, you need to change `type="b"` in `type = "l"`.

Then, if I understand right, you are willing to  plot each time series individually, right ? So, having one time serie per plot ?

For doing that, you can use `par(mfrow` to cut your plotting areas in multiple pieces.
As `ts.plot` required  two times series to be plot, you can cheat using the first color as white to not have db[,1] plotted on each plot:

```r
par(mfrow = c(ncol(db),1))
for(i in 1:ncol(db))
{
  ts.plot(cbind(db[,1], y = db[,i]), type= "l", gpars = list(col = c("white","red")), main = paste0("Copper & ",colnames(db)[i]))
}
```

[image]

If you need to have db[,1] plotted on each of them, you can just do that:

```r
par(mfrow = c(ncol(db)-1,1))
for(i in 2:ncol(db))
{
  ts.plot(cbind(db[,1], y = db[,i]), type= "l", gpars = list(col = c("black","red")), main = paste0("Copper & ",colnames(db)[i]))
}
```

And you get:

### [image]

**Use of ggplot2**

Now, to get the same plot in `ggplot2`, you have to reshape your dataframe in order to get it compatible with `ggplot` grammar. You can achieve it using `tidyverse` library:

```r
library(tidyverse)
data.frame(db) %>% 
  mutate(Time = seq(1:100)) %>%
  pivot_longer(., -Time,names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") 

# A tibble: 400 x 3
    Time Variable   Value
   <int> <fct>      <dbl>
 1     1 x        -0.626 
 2     1 y         0.380 
 3     1 z         2.41  
 4     1 u         3.89  
 5     2 x         0.184 
 6     2 y         1.04  
 7     2 z         3.69  
 8     2 u         1.95  
 9     3 x        -0.836 
10     3 y         0.0891
# … with 390 more rows
```

So, now our dataset is ready to be plotted using this code:

```r
data.frame(db) %>% 
  mutate(Time = seq(1:100)) %>%
  pivot_longer(., -Time,names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Value") %>%
  mutate(Variable = factor(Variable, levels = c("x","y","z","u")))%>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Time, y = Value, color = Variable)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(Variable))
  facet_wrap(Variable~.)
```

To get:
[image]

Does it answer your question ?